# How to solve circular import problem on graphviz?

Tags: python, neo4j, graphviz

I am using graphviz package with neo4j. When I try to run the code, I am getting the following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'diGraph' from partially initialized module 'graphviz' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

The code is as follows:

```
from graphviz import diGraph 
from neo4j import GraphDatabase
def getCI(tx, dot, fontcolor, edge_width, show_lifecycle):
    ##building the graph here##
dot = diGraph(comment='Query Result')
dot.attr("graph",rankdir="LR",margin="0",compound="true", ratio="fill", size="8.3,11.7!")
with driver.session() as session:
 session.read_transaction(getCI, dot,  c_white, 8, False)


file = open("bpic14_query.dot","w") 
file.write(dot.source)
file.close()
```

Could anyone help me with this issue?

Thanks!!

Comment: `from graphviz import Digraph` (as per the [docs](https://graphviz.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#basic-usage)). Also you shouldn't get that error to begin with, it's an indication that something else is wrong. You should be getting `cannot import name 'diGraph' from 'graphviz'` and then a pointer to the actual file. Make sure your file name isn't `graphviz.py` anywhere.

Comment: Thank you @Torxed!! My file name was making all the confusion, as you said it should not be graphviz.py, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

```
from graphviz import diGraph
```

Should be;

```
from graphviz import Digraph
```

Think that solves it, but maybe i am missing something